# Type arguments should be specified for an outer class

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

> I am implementing oauth2 security  in my application through create an
> config class but I don't know where I make mistake I get following
> type of compile time error

```
Type arguments should be specified for an outer class 'ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer'. Use full class name to specify them
```

> SecurityConfig.kt

```
package com.main.serviceproduct.config

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(security: HttpSecurity){
        security.authorizeRequests(Customizer { authorize: ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry ->
            authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()
        })
            .oauth2ResourceServer{obj: OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity?>->obj.jwt()}
    }

}

security.authorizeRequests(Customizer { authorize: ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry ->
            authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

> I got error on above line at this point authorize:
> ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry` is a inner (non-static) class so it needs the type information of the outer class `ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<T>`, which actually is a `HttpSecurity`.

The below should works:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
open class SecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(security: HttpSecurity){
        security.authorizeRequests(Customizer { authorize: ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry ->
            authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()
        })
            .oauth2ResourceServer{obj: OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity?> ->obj.jwt()}
    }

}
```